# How to run a method after a diagnostic has analyzed a compilation completely?

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn, compiler-services

I am implementing `DiagnosticAnalyzer` for analyzing a `CompilationWithAnalyzers` object using the roslyn compiler library. I wish to add an event at the exhaustion of a single diangosticanalyzer, but have been unable to find such a hook. The only similar event I have seen is `AnalysisContext.RegisterCompilationAction` but it triggers at the completion of a *compilation*, not an analysis.

Does such an event exist? is there another way to fulfill the same goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do not currently have any API that allows an analyzer to interact with the analysis engine.  We would like to keep the engine an implementation detail that we can change and improve over time. For more information on how the engine works today, you can look [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/docs/analyzers/Analyzer%20Actions%20Semantics.md)